# Brackets Code Complete Not working

Tags: adobe-brackets

I have installed Brackets with Tern Intelligence.

Inside my file `Main.js`, I type the following thing

## `Math.`

And press `ctrl-enter`. I imagine I should see `pow`,`max`,etc, show up. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Code hints should appear automatically - no need to press anything. (If you do want to trigger them manually though, it's Ctrl-Space, not Ctrl-Enter).

What's in the rest of your Main.js file?  If you make a new, blank JS file does it work? When I type `Math.` in an empty .js file, I see a list of code hints both while I'm typing `Math` *and* the appropriate list of options after typing the `.`

Also, try using *Debug > Reload Without Extensions* to make sure you don't have an extension installed that could be causing a problem.